# How can I activate an animation once all inputs are filled?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have 3 inputs inside a div and a submit button. I've loaded in an animation from a library and added it to the submit button.

What I want is the submit button to animate once all three inputs have some kind of value in them (at least one character).

Below is what I have so far, but it's not working. What do I need to add or change?

```js
$allInputFields = $('#inputFields .inputSection input')
$submitButton = $('#submitButton')
$submitButton.removeClass('animate__animated', 'animate__tada')

for (let i = 0; i < $allInputFields; i++) {
    if ($allInputFields[i].value) {
        $submitButton.toggleClass('animate__animated', 'animate__tada')
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
<!-- Animation from Animate.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="inputFields">
    
          <div class="inputSection">
              <h3>input 1</h3>
              <input>
          </div>

          <div class="inputSection">
            <h3>input 2</h3>
            <input>
          </div>

          <div class="inputSection">
            <h3>input 3</h3>
            <input>
          </div>

    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    
    <div>
            <button id="submitButton" class="animate__animation animate__wobble">Submit</button>
        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the form tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each` loop to check if any input is empty or not depending on this addClass `animate__tada` or remove it if added previously.

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(".inputSection input").on("change", function() {
  var flag = true; //set flag
  $("#submitButton").removeClass('animate__tada').addClass('animate__animated') //add default class
  //loop through each inputs
  $("#inputFields .inputSection input").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().trim() == "") {
      flag = false; //if empty 
      return false //exit
    }
  })
  //if true
  if (flag) {
    $("#submitButton").removeClass('animate__animated').addClass('animate__tada') //all ok...
  }
})
```

```css
.animate__animated {
  color: red;
}

.animate__tada {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Animation from Animate.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />


<div id="inputFields">

  <div class="inputSection">
    <h3>input 1</h3>
    <input>
  </div>

  <div class="inputSection">
    <h3>input 2</h3>
    <input>
  </div>

  <div class="inputSection">
    <h3>input 3</h3>
    <input>
  </div>

</div>

<br>
<br>

<div>
  <button id="submitButton" class="animate__animation animate__wobble">Submit</button>
</div>
```